# macports install obsolete port

Tags: pyqt, osx-yosemite, macports

When I execute `sudo port install py33-pyqt5` in my terminal, I get this error message:

```
--->  Configuring py33-pyqt5
Error: py33-pyqt5 has been made obsolete by the port py34-pyqt5. Please install py34-pyqt5 instead.
Error: org.macports.configure for port py33-pyqt5 returned: obsolete port
Please see the log file for port py33-pyqt5 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-graveyard/py33-pyqt5/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port py33-pyqt5 failed
```

But I need to install `py33-pyqt5` and not `py34-pyqt5`. Is there a possible way to install the old version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach that is used to install an older port: http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort. For a Python port that uses the subport feature, that probably means finding an older version of the Portfile that now provides py34-pyqt5 that did still provide py33-pyqt5 and running `sudo port install -- subport=py33-pyqt5` in a directory that contains this older Portfile. Note that the Portfile and the directory must be readable by the `macports` user, so your home directory will probably not work very well. I recommend a place in `/tmp`.

There has been a decision to phase out support for python 3.3 in MacPorts, though -- you will run into more and more problems when trying to use Python 3.3, so you should really consider switching to a newer version.